# When to call wait() on super

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

When to invoke `super.wait()`, something like below -

```
synchronized (this)
      {
        while (true)
        {
          try
          {
            super.wait();
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            return;
          }

        }
 }
```

Comment: Before we answer you need to say atleast, What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, that's a weird construct and most likely a bug. 
but it's still valid. 
why all the down votes?

Comment: Well, I saw this in one of the answers by @bdonlan in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114320/java-monitors-how-to-know-if-waitlong-timeout-ended-by-timeout-or-by-notify). And this is the first time I saw wait being invoked on super. So asked this question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.wait()` is declared final and cannot be overridden.
So `super.wait()` always means just `wait()` but is a bit longer.

Comment: There is no attempt at override in the original poster's code.

Comment: I'm saying that in this situation wait and super.wait are equivalent because wait() is always in a superclass.

Comment: What do you mean by "...but is a bit longer"?

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` must be called on the same object on which it it `synchronized` otherwise it will result in `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`

It should be `this.wait()`

Comment: "this" and "super" both always refer to the same object.  The difference between this.foo() and super.foo() only matters when the a foo() method is defined in both the object's class and in the class of one of the class's ancestors.  Then "super" allows a call to the ancestor's version of the function.  The normal use case is when you define this.foo() as a wrapper around the inherited function.