# How to understand if wait() returned from timeout or from a notify()?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a waiting thread:

```
synchronized(sharedCounter) {
  while(sharedCounter > 0) {
    sharedCounter.wait(60000); //wait at most 1 minute
    /*if it wakens from the end of the timeout, it should break the loop
      or it could potentially restart the timeout*/
  }
}
```

And a thread that can notify:

```
synchronized (sharedCounter) {
  if(sharedCounter == 0) 
    sharedCounter.notify(); 
}
```

**How can I distinguish a notify from a timeout?**

I could do something like this:

```
synchronized(sharedCounter) {
  while(sharedCounter > 0) {
    sharedCounter.wait(60000); 
    if(sharedCounter == -1) { //if it was a notify()
      //I could save the fact that it was a notify() here
      break;
    }
    //Otherwirse, assume it was a timeout, save the fact and break
    break;
  }
}

synchronized (sharedCounter) {
   if(sharedCounter == 0) {
     sharedCounter = -1; //to signal that it comes from a notify()
     sharedCounter.notify(); 
   }
}
```

**The problem is, that a spurious wake up would spoil my design.**

How would you handle this problem?

Comment: What is `sharedCounter`?

Comment: Adding to hagrawal's comment, I am very concerned about you use of `sharedCounter`.  I don't think it's an integer, otherwise you wouldn't be able to synchronize on it.  So I assume it's an `Integer`.  But it seems dangerous to synchronize on a variable that you are constantly reassigning.

Comment: You should never assume anything about why `wait()` returned:  It should be able to _find out_ why.  The wait/notify mechanism is a low-level primitive that is meant to be used in a very specific way to implement higher-level synchronization objects:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590542/java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-object-not-locked-by-thread-before-wait/26593239#26593239

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a more sophisticated concurrency primitive, a [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html). Acquire one from a [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) with [`Lock#newCondition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition--). You then have access to a [`Condition#await(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method which returns a `boolean` with a value of

> `false` if the waiting time detectably elapsed before return from the method, else `true`

For example,

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
// ... (share the object across threads)
if (condition.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    // signaled (equivalent of notify)
} else {
    // time elapsed
}
// ... (in other thread)
condition.signal();
```

Spurious wakeups, unless otherwise specified in the `Condition` implementation documentation, are handled internally. You don't have to worry about them.

Comment: Obviously, before calling condition.await(...), I should acquire the lock?

Comment: @kami Yes. And `await` releases the corresponding `Lock` until it returns.

Comment: Thanks, it was perfect. Just a question, I am in a scenario where multiple signals could occur. Are they simply ignored (after receiving the firtst one)?

Comment: @Kami An `await`-ing `Condition` will consider a single `signal`. Any other `signal` calls will go to other `await`-ing threads or ignored if there are no other threads waiting on the `Condition`.

Comment: The documentation recommends "programmers always assume that [spurious wakeups] can occur". Are you suggesting that doesn't apply to a timed wait?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. You will have to add logic to your multithreaded application yourself to distinguish between these cases.

Comment: A spurious wake up would mess up with the timeout. If it has waited for 30 seconds, I would have no way to reset the wait to only 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds.

Comment: Actually I found this answer for the timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178399/java-how-to-distinguish-between-spurious-wakeup-and-timeout-in-wait It suggests to keep track of the time.

Comment: @Kami: that would be a terrible solution, since there is no way to tell whether you were notified "just in time" or wether the timeout has passed.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking to combine it with some 'hidden message' like the -1 above. It stil feels like it is not the most clean solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false problem. If, for example, wait returned by timeout, but immediately after that sharedCounter was set to -1 - do you still want to react to timeout, or to -1?